# Transparent edges

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have an app that uses transparency so that the background of the app is a custom shape. The problem I am having is the rounded corners are jagged. Not a nice clean rounded corner like you would see on an icon or widget. I have tried several different image types (i.e. PNG, GIF, etc). But it seems when I use the transparency Key the quality on the edges gets worse . Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you paste some code?

Comment: Don't take this wrong, but WPF was made for that. Set window to transparent and make a border, stuff goes inside the border.

Comment: @RachelGallen I just set the transparency key to magenta and added background image to the main form, i still can see pixels of the magenta color at the border.

Thank you for your quick responce!

Comment: @whoKnows i know there is a way with WPF but how do you set to regular form please explain more.

links would be helpful
Thank you for your quick responce!

Comment: When you say how do you set in regular form - you saying you want to do it with Windows forms? If so, Form with no border style use the transparencyKey then one option is to draw a custom rectangle with rounded corners if desired and paint the surface of the rectangle, controls will float inside of the rectangle area we just drew. As mentioned above show us some code. And all form properties related to your form.

Comment: i found a solution

i just drew small pixel dots around the corners with photophop pen...that kept a nice boarder! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution i just drew small pixel dots around the corners with photophop pen...that kept a nice boarder! Thanks